# Выборка из базы данных при помощи LIMIT с помощью массива без bind'a

Tags: php, массивы, pdo

Здравствуйте!

Как отправить запрос на выборку с участием LIMIT'a через PDO, при помощи массива и без участия bind'a?

Пробую так:

```
$array_db = Array(0, 10);
$sql = $db->prepare("select * from `table` limit ?, ?");
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sql->execute($array_db);
$row = $sql->fetchAll();
```

В итоге выдает ошибку:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '10'' at line 1

Спасибо!

Comment: 8 лет назад http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php#76966

Comment: Этот вариант, я пробовал. Он мне не помог решить проблему.

Comment: Я не про вариант, а про ваш баг, которому 8 лет (если не больше). Вот такая бредовая запись `$array_db = Array((int)0, (int)10);` тоже не сработает?

Comment: @Visman Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не надо принимать неработающие ответы. Это наносит огромный вред как сайту, так и тем, кто придет в этот вопрос через поиск.

Про то что не надо писать бессмысленных ответов, я говорить не буду - это все равно бесполезно.

**Правильный** ответ на вопрос, "Как отправить запрос на выборку с участием LIMIT'a без участия bind'a?" будет [отключить режим эмуляции](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#limit):

```
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

Comment: Где же вы раньше-то были!? Ответ удалить не могу без снятия "правильного ответа".